# Accepting form-data in ASP.NET Core 3.1 REST API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-3.1, form-data

I'm trying to create a REST service that is able to accept form-data. I am using the `[FromForm]` attribute but the object's properties are filled with null values.

I have the following endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public ActionResult<UploadResponse> Upload([FromForm] UploadRequest req)
{
    ...do something
}
```

UploadRequest.cs:

```
public class UploadRequest
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public string CaseId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I post form-data using Postman like this:

[image]

The request parameter is filled with null values, though:

[image]

I have tried matching the case of parameters, adding and removing "multipart/form-data" header but nothing works for me. What am I missing?

Comment: UploadRequest is written rather than UploadLvRequest. Change and try

Comment: @pc_coder I'm sorry, it's just a typo in this question. Didn't check it properly. However, in code everything fits. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a rough time seeking for a solution I found out that I was missing *boundary* in Content-Type header. So the Content-Type header should look as following: `multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>`.